# Creating a portable application using text-file datasets

Tags: c#

I have a windows form application which works with data sets that are text files. I tested the application on other systems and it works, properly.But for running the application the data sets must copy into `C Drive` directly. Is there any solution for running the application without copying the data sets into `C Drive` or any directory?

The form of my script to read the dataset?

```
StreamReader fileitem = new StreamReader("c:\\dataset.txt");
```

I hope to get your detailed comments.

Comment: What are you actually asking .... can C# read data files from another location .... a UNC path (like \\server\share\folder\file.txt) or other lettered drive like D: E: etc .... sure.  If its not that question, what is it?

Comment: whatever is your folder path, use that path with the StreamReader.

Comment: You can put the file name/path in the App.config and read the value from there.  Then different instances of the application can be configured to use different file locations.

Comment: ... and there is another interpretation, i.e. "how do I configure a different location for my data, so its not hardcoded".  You need to be more clear otherwise we cannot help.

Comment: I have my application on the pen drive, I want to run it without copy anything into the system @Selman22 even the data sets. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I have my application on the pen drive, I want to run it without copy anything into the system @iandotkelly even the data sets. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Well, you don't need to use absolute paths, like c:\dataset.txt - you can use a relative path like 'mydatafolder\\dataset.txt' which would be a folder relative to where the application exe was.  Its worth pointing out that (depending on how big the files are and how often they are read to do the analysis) that this might be actually slower than copying the app, as a USB pen drive is a lot slower than a hard-disk.

Comment: Would you please clear your answer more,@iandotkelly. Also, What do you mean by EXE file (you mean the file which is located at the .....bin/debug/ path?

Comment: @iandotkelly. if my exe file is in "function/fuction/bin/debug" path. what can be the relative path?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are looking for `System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath`. [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

That is an environment variable, which gives you the path for where your exe file started. This means, if you run your app from a USB drive G:\MyApp. You could use:

```
StreamReader fileitem = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "dataset.txt"));
```

Comment: Thanks @celerno. Is there any way to detect the path dynamically? I maen for example for "StreamReader fileitem = new StreamReader("c:\\dataset.txt")". if I changed the path to another oneit changes automatically?

Comment: I've added details to the answer. Read the link i've posted on :Source: